# Word Space Between footnote and note

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

I'm trying to set the space between footnote and note to 5mm.

But I can't find any setting in Microsoft.office.interop.word.

I'm developing in c#.

does anyone know how I can do that?

Comment: Use LaTeX instead of MS-Word. (Sorry, could not resist)

Answer (score 0):

The footnote number (in the footnote) and the rest of the footnote text make up a normal paragraph.

So, you can separate the number and the text with a tab (5mm).  And set indentation on the paragraph to hanging (5mm).